Optimizing React App with built in search for Google SEO
I have a client-side rendered SPA React app. For this post, I'll use cake-shops.com as an example. The Cake shop data is stored in the database and the client queries data API. Client supplies X and Y coordinates to the backend and the API service can efficiently return cake shops near those coordinates supplied.
My goal is to make this page discoverable by Google.
I have an idea how to make it work but I don't know if I'm thinking about this the right way.
I can implement dynamic routing that will return results depending on what is specified in the URL. For example, visiting cake-shops.com/search/tokyo the app will return results from Tokyo, Japan. It won't be hard-coded, it would simply check the parameter (Tokyo in this example) in Google Maps API, get the best match, and return query results based on that match. So following this pattern cake-shops.com/search/{any-location} app can almost always return results from the desired location.
I can also update the page title and meta tags programmatically so in that case page title would be Cake shops in Tokyo, Japan a tag would be updated in the HTML document:
<meta name="description" content="Cake shops in Tokyo, Japan">
My goal is the following:
if someone is searching: shops in {any-location} on Google, I want my website to appear in the search with this URL cake-shops.com/search/any-location.
I doubt this because I'm unsure if Google's web crawlers would discover that page. This page is not clickable anywhere, the only way to access it is by manually typing in the URL.
Am I thinking the right way about this? How did Trip Advisor do it?

Google knows a lot about what's going on on the internet since it has embedded itself in almost every website, probably even yours, and can therefore follow any user going to your search pages. However, to be sure Google can see every search location you have, you could create a sitemap.

With regards to "How did Trip Advisor do it?", they don't index their search results pages.  Their robots.txt file actually blocks it from being crawled, and they have a noindex meta tag on the results page.  This is what Google actually advise you to do with internal search.
Instead, they have navigations and breadcrumbs to allow people to navigate round the site by following links, plus both html and xml sitemaps.  I'd be surprised if any page on their site needs the search engine to be found.  If people can't also find your pages via the navigation, there is likely a UX problem as well as an SEO problem.
